# sfErrorNotifierPlugin on symfony task

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-plugins

My application runs huge batch processing inside a Symfony task, and I want to be notified about all PHP errors and uncaught exceptions.

So I tried sfErrorNotifierPlugin, and it works great in a web context (accessing the application from the browser); the problem is that I can't make it work on my symfony tasks.

Is there any way to make it work in tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for your help @Maerlyn, my solution is not much different from yours.

I solved the problem overriding the doRun method on my tasks this way:

```
protected function doRun(sfCommandManager $commandManager, $options)
{
    try
    {
      return parent::doRun($commandManager, $options);

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      $this->dispatcher->notifyUntil(new sfEvent($e, 'application.throw_exception'));
      throw $e;
    }
  }
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

in ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
public function setup()
  {
    if ('cli' == php_sapi_name()) $this->disablePlugins('sfErrorNotifierPlugin');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

`sfTask` has no exception handling like the web interface does, but you can work around it: ultimately exceptions thrown are passed to [`sfErrorNotifier::notifyException`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfErrorNotifierPlugin/trunk/lib/sfErrorNotifier.php#L39).

Wrap your task's `execute` method in a big try-catch block:

```
public function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
{
  try {
    //your code here
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    sfErrorNotifier::notifyException($e); //call the notifier
    throw $e; //rethrow to stop execution and to avoid problems in some special cases
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that it needs an application parameter to run correctly (uses settings from app.yml).

Comment: This is cool. Is there any other sfNotifier that allows you to read the messages printed to console, so that they can be displayed in the web-application? This could actually be the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085939/display-output-from-a-symfony-task-on-a-template