# Display output from a Symfony task on a template

Tags: symfony1, logging, task

I am executing a task from an action in Symfony. I wish to capture the output from the task & display it to the (admin) user. Do I extract it from the dispatcher / log or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, however, in a task you can log to a seperate file like so (within the execute function in the task class):

```
$fileLogger = new sfFileLogger($this->dispatcher, 
                               array('file' =>$this->configuration->getRootDir().'/log/foobar.log'));
$this->dispatcher->connect('command.log', array($fileLogger, 'listenToLogEvent'));
```

And then in your task when you use:

```
$this->logSection('something', 'Log whatever message you want....', 1000);
```

It will automatically log to the custom log file.

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks Jamie. But that will be quite a work around to log to a diff file, and then read it out to display the log info. Besides, I want to use this with some std Doctrine tasks. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why not just perform the task within the action - and format the output in the template ? why are you running a separate task from an Action ? (i know this thread is old)